# Utility to identify what mouse buttons are being pressed?

Tags: applications, mouse, input-source

Is there a utility for mac to show what mouse buttons are being pressed?

Similar utilities for Windows are: Spy++ and WindowSpy from AutoHotKey.

For Linux I have used: `xinput --query-state`

Comment: Magic mouse only or also generic mice?

Comment: I would like so see the info for any mouse. I don’t have a Magic mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org/) can be scripted to do this.

- Install Hammerspoon and run it.
- Open `System Preferences`, go to `Security & Privacy` and enable `Hammerspoon.app` under `Accessibility`.
- Click the Hammerspoon menu icon and select `Open Config`. Your default code/text editor will open to `~/.hammerspoon/init.lua`.
- Enter something like the following text which uses the [Hammerspoon hs.eventtap.new](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.eventtap.html#new) API to listen for events.

```lua
detectMouseDown = hs.eventtap.new({ 
  hs.eventtap.event.types.otherMouseDown,
  hs.eventtap.event.types.leftMouseDown,
  hs.eventtap.event.types.rightMouseDown
}, function(e)
  local button = e:getProperty(
      hs.eventtap.event.properties['mouseEventButtonNumber']
  )
  print(string.format("Clicked Mouse Button: %i", button))
end)

detectMouseDown:start()
```

- Save the file.
- Click the Hammerspoon menu icon, select `Console...` and click `Reload config` on the console window.
- Now, whenever you click anywhere you'll see a log entry in the Hammerspoon Console!

(So far, this works for any type of touchpad click/tap or external mouse click.)

Answer (score 5):

[Karabiner-EventViewer](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html#eventviewer) is another option that can log the information you are looking for. Although it comes as part of Karabiner-Elements you can use it independently to monitor keystrokes and mouse button presses.

> You can examine keyboard and mouse events by using EventViewer.
>   Launch Karabiner-EventViewer from Launchpad.
>
> Input events will be shown when you type keyboard on EventViewer or press pointing buttons on Mouse Area.
>
> --source [Karabiner-EventViewer manual](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html#eventviewer)

In practice I find it logs keys and clicks made any where whilst it is running.

[image: screenshot of the Karabiner-Event viewer interface]

Comment: +1, Karabiner Elements is so useful in so many ways. If you're going to install something, better this than anything else.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it would work correctly, but `xinput` is included in [XQuartz](https://xquartz.org), an implementation of the X Window System for macOS. You can invoke it via Terminal.

Comment: Not really as I think that goes through another mapping process.